# Navigation Drawer item

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

If I click the Gallery in Navigation drawer item,I need to create a separate activity for Gallery page.Below I am posted the codes what I am tried so far.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }


private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new GalleryFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new PhotosFragment();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
```

**GalleryFragment.java:**

```
public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chapter, container, false);

    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), GalleryActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);

    return rootView;
}
```

}

**gallery.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
```

**GalleryActivity.java:**

```
public class GalleryActivity extends Activity {

    TextView textView1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gallery_activity);

        textView1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);


    }

}
```

**gallery_activity.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Lesson Page" />

</LinearLayout>
```

So far I do it like this.But it wasn't working.In output,Firstly I am getting the separate activity for Gallery. then if I click the back button it displays the home page.But If I click the Gallery in Navigation Drawer,it doesn't move to the separate gallery activity.There was no error in logcat.

Comment: What happens when it "does not work"?

Comment: @Henry no log error.But it doesn't working means it doesn't move to the separate activity.

Answer (score 0):

The code in `displayView` does effectively nothing (assuming there is not something you did not post). It sets a local variable `fragment` that goes out of scope when the method ends.

If you want to start the `GalleryActivity` you need code similar to this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, GalleryActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Now I am getting null pointer exception at this line `Intent i = new Intent(context, GalleryActivity.class);`

Comment: I wrote *similar*. The lines were not meant to be copied verbatim. You need to set the `context` parameter to a valid context.

Comment: I do it like this.`private static Context mContext;` then `Intent i = new Intent(mContext, GalleryActivity.class);`

Comment: And where do you initialize `mContext`? Moreover, it should most likely not be static.

Comment: `private Context mContext;` then `mContext=getApplicationContext();` then `private void displayView(int position) {
  
     Fragment fragment = null;
  switch (position) {
  case 0:
  //fragment = new DisplayFragment();` then next line
   `Intent i = new Intent(mContext, DisplayActivity.class);
   startActivity(i);
   
   break;` finally I am getting the error in logcat failed to create fragment.But my applicaiton doesn't stop.